# How to export a signed android app on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

On Android studio, I have fully completed my code and have tested it on my physical device. I have not generated an apk file yet. I have searched around on StackOverflow and all I know now is that I need to export signed to release it on the play store. Now I'm staring at a form not knowing what anything does.

[image]

Someone explain please

EDIT: The solution --> [developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html](http://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: The first thing you should do without flinching is go through this link - https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: Do you see the button at the bottom that says "Help"?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new keystore to use when signing...there is a "Create New" button on that form.

Once you have created the keystore, you will know the information to use to complete this form(make sure you keep track of that, once you have signed you app with this keystore, and uploaded to the Play store, it is permanent, if you forget it you will be in trouble).

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Buid (menu bar) -> Generate Signed APK` and follow the steps shown in the wizard.

Updating from my comment below:

Select a keystore if you have one else create one using the provided button. Enter the passwords in this window again (same as ones you provide when creating the keystore). Make sure you select a date in far future for the certificate validity otherwise you'll not be able to sign your apk after the certificate expires

Comment: Build (menu bar) -> Generate Signed APK gives me the same form as seen in the question

Comment: yes, select a keystore if you have one else create one using the provided button. Enter the passwords in this window again (same as ones you provide when creating the keystore). Make sure you select a date in far future for the certificate validity otherwise you'll not be able to sign your apk after the certificate expires.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the menu bar, click Build > Generate Signed APK.
2. Select the module you would like to release from the drop down, and click Next.
3. On the New Key Store window, provide the following information for your keystore and key.
4. Keystore
5. Key store path: Select the location where your keystore should be created.
6. Password: Create and confirm a secure password for your keystore.
   Key
7. Alias: Enter an identifying name for your key.
8. Password: Create and confirm a secure password for your key. This
   should be different from the password you chose for your keystore
9. Validity (years): Set the length of time in years that your key will
   be valid. Your key should be valid for at least 25 years, so you can
   sign app updates with the same key through the lifespan of your app.
10. Certificate: Enter some information about yourself for your
     certificate. This information is not displayed in your app, but is
     included in your certificate as part of the APK.
11. Once you complete the form, click OK.
12. On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, select a keystore, a
     private key, and enter the passwords for both. (If you created your
     keystore in the last step, these fields are already populated for
     you.) Then click Next.
13. On the next window, select a destination for the signed APK(s),
     select the build type, (if applicable) choose the product
     flavor(s), and click Finish.